# Fetch content from WordPress through javascript or iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, woocommerce

I have a product that displays all of its content on a specific product tag (WooCommerce). For example, product image and product description. How do I fetch the content of this and display it through an iframe or javascript (is there another better way?)? Note that I will be fetching one product, only, from the product tag archive.

I want other people to get this code and display it in their widget (blogs). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do that with the JSON API plugin for Wordpress !

I use it to get certain posts to my mobile app (android/iOS).

http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/